# About the chosen songs and music of Movies

Tags: production, soundtrack, music-video

If you pay attention on chosen songs of a movie, series, etc... you will realize that the whole set of songs aren't random, despite the fact that you may not perceive while you are watching the whole production.

But, in the case of productions using modern songs and music, I think is more difficult to understand the motivations of the creators on "why use a particular song in a scene". I think in many times it is due to the instrumental character, like "it sounds cool". But sometimes you can see a reasoning on why they chose a particular song (beyond the composed original soundtrack).

> Examples:
>
> Guardians of the Galaxy: "The Rubberband man"
>
> Lucky Hank: "Silver Timothy"

The lyrics of both the songs don't match the scenes directly, but the instrumental part gives a awesome flavor for the scene.

Therefore, I'm starting to realize that maybe there are specific people choosing these songs by hand. So, my question is:

**Are there any sources of references that teaches you how to choose a soundtrack for a movie?**

Comment: Theres no set path for that sort of role, like many roles in the movie business, you work your way up (or out...) to that position. Quite often a director might have a tune in mind or have almost last say on a selection, but the role of picking and licensing music would go to a Music Supervisor or something similar. Like when wanting to work with cameras, you try and intern and work your way up, building connections, gaining experience, focused within that group, same for the music dept.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking. [From Review](https://movies.stackexchange.com/review/first-questions/94465)

Comment: Your question will be better received if you were to just ask for the considerations that precede selecting music for a film (and even then focus your question a little more, for example by describing a particular movie and a particular scene in it). As it is, asking for references or sources is off-topic.

Comment: I agree this question would fit better here if it were edited to basically ask, “how does one become the person who selects songs for a movie or TV show?” The preamble about how important music can be in a movie is unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

The job you are talking about is often called a “music supervisor”. Berklee College of Music has a page about becoming one:

https://www.berklee.edu/careers/roles/music-supervisor-filmtv

A few quotes about becoming a music supervisor from the page linked above:

> Aspiring music supervisors should do whatever they can to get their first credits—performing music supervision for student films, for example. Keep in mind that music supervision isn't just about picking the right song for the job; it's also about negotiating the rights to the song, a task that requires strong professional connections and a reputation in the music licensing world. Aspiring music supervisors might consider doing an internship at a music publisher, possibly in the licensing department.

> **Professional Skills**
>
> - Encyclopedic music knowledge (different genres, periods, etc.)
> - Film knowledge
> - Music licensing laws
> - Connections in the music recording and publishing industries
> - Negotiation
> - Deadlines
> - Research

Comment: Thanks Todd. Actually, the last topic is the most nebulous to me, since how can I research a perfect song for a scene? I mean, for instance, how "The Rubberband man" was choosen to be the "right" song for this scene[1]? My guess: because it sounds cool, but this isn't a technical explanation haha. Even a better one: the character likes it. [1] https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cz23Cw-Z6SE

Comment: "Encyclopedic music knowledge (different genres, periods, etc.)" might be more important to choose songs to match the movie. The music supervisor should have a wide knowledge of music and be able to recall the sounds and names of songs. When they are reading the script or watching dailies, they should be able to come up with ideas for songs that would work. They also may assemble their own databases or access databases of songs with keywords, tempos, keys, instrumentation, etc., to help them find the right songs.